# How to replace json file in release in VSTS CD?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, continuous-delivery

While deploying a  build to multiple environments like UAT, Production. I want to replace one file config.uat.json or config.prod.json with config.json. Is there any option available? just like we have XML Transformation.

I am aware of Json Variable substitution but that doesn't serve my purpose as the variable list is long (almost 50 entries)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why do you think Json Variable substitution doesn't serve your purpose?

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry for late reply. Json variable subsition won't be a good solution since the list is very long and a frequent update is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `Program.cs` file, you can get an environment variable which will represent your current environment:

```
var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
var currentEnv = builder.GetSetting("environnement");
```

using this `currentEnv` value, you will be able to load the file `config.{currentEnv}.json`

```
builder.AddJsonFile($"config.{currentEnv}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to do this in powershell, you can make a transofmration of your configuration file with a default: appsettings.json containing keys, and appsettings.env.json containing overriding.

To transform your configuration, you can do something like this:

```
Param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$SpecificConfig
)
$defaultConfig = "AppSettings.json";
$settingsContent = ConvertFrom-Json $defaultConfig;
$specificContent = ConvertFrom-Json $SpecificConfig;

# Do this on each <property> to override
if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($specificContent.<property>))
{
    $settingsContent.<property> = $specificContent.<property>;
}
Write-Host $settingsContent > $defaultConfig;
```

Comment: One of the solutions I thought of if quite similar. I was wondering if there is a way we can do json transformation just like xml transformation

Comment: You can, but as far as I know, there is no built-in tool to do this properly.
In powershell, you can load your AppSettings.json with ConvertFrom-Json $file.
An Edit will be made to complete the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will try replacing using powershell

Answer (score 2):

[JSON variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=vsts#json-variable-substitution) should be a good option, if you don't want to add variables one by one on `Variables` tab, you can update them with VSTS REST API, or add a powershell script to set the variables.

Otherwise, you may need to delete the config.uat.json or config.prod.json, and copy the  config.json to the target machine.